# Grub 2.02 Command-line from USB, load windows 10 from HDD

Tags: grub2

*chainloader=bootmgfw.efi*    ok,
*chainloader=/Windows/System32/winload.efi*  ok.
But I dont see any impact of *winload.efi*, same as without it.
I want to load BCD without win installation disk.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my dual boot computer I have edited the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to add a menuentry for another drive,

```
menuentry "External drive on (hd2) [hd{0,1,2,3} edit if necessary]" {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd2)'
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}
```

Your internal drive will probably not be seen by grub as `(hd2)`. Please edit to make the menuentry point to the correct drive specification, I guess `(hd1)` or `(hd0)`.

---

- If you have a full installed system in your USB drive

  - it might work directly to run

    ```
    sudo update-grub
    ```

    and grub will find Windows 'automatically' and add it to the grub menu.
  - otherwise edit `40_custom` inspired by my menuentry.

    After writing the edits, you should run the command

    ```
    sudo update-grub
    ```

---

- If you have a bare-bones grub system in your USB drive

  edit the menuentry directly into the file

  ```
  grub.cfg
  ```

  often but not always located in the directory `/boot/grub`

Comment: further manual research revealed impact on BCD store: bootmgfw.efi adds 1 entry for all, winload.efi adds its entry on every load of grub.cfg as "windows", both are not sufficient to boot Windows, some entries are lacking. Winload.efi is not like winload.exe in its impact. Cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277373/is-it-possible-to-use-grub-to-run-an-efi-binary   The point is that those .efi files are not documented. Command "chainloader +1" is for MBR systems only.